# CSS img won't resize

Tags: css, image, resize

Total newbie here, tried to google my issue, even get on the second page of results... I'm stuck on resizing image and I have no idea why it is not working, hoping someone can help. By using Inspect on Chrome I can see that element for img is not being connected to the img and I have no idea why.

Block below is within <main>

```
      <article>
        <section class="article-content">
          <img src="./assets/images/page_screenshot.png" alt=""/>
        </section>
      </article>
```

Here is CSS that I have for the whole part.

```
main {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: var(--main-bgc);
    padding-top: 5%;
}

article {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    width: 100%;
}

.article-title {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    color: var(--font-colot-slate);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--font-color-white);
}

.article-title h2 {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.article-content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    float: right;
    color: var(--font-color-white);
}

.article-content img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

I tried adding height and width in  tag and works fine, but not very happy with that solution.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code. The line in your CSS where you target the image (`.article-content img`) is correct and should resize the image to 100x100 pixels. What's happening instead?

Comment: Here's a test with similar code where the image resizes properly: https://jsfiddle.net/CCMars/6hdp0jmw/

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've given us works fine, as you can see in this snippet (run it to see the result). So if your image is not being properly resized, it must be because of some other part of your code, which you haven't included.

If you want the image to retain its original aspect ratio, you can add `object-fit: cover;` which will crop the image rather than squash it.

```css
article {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    width: 100%;
}

.article-content {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90%;
    float: right;
    color: var(--font-color-white);
}

.article-content img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section class="article-content">
    <img src="https://shotkit.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/night-landscape-photography-featured.jpg">
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: It was rest of the code, somewhere between edits I moved my style.css file to css folder but was keep editing original file. Because I was playing only with the img that time, didn't realise it. Feel so stupid now, but thanks for the help!